# Install Libreoffice SDK in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

How can I install the libreoffice SDK in Ubuntu 12.10? Is it available in the repositories already or do I have to manually install it, if so how and what prerequisites are needed to install it as I have a fresh ubuntu install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is available! Try

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-dev
```

in terminal session or install package in package manager.

Comment: I've finally found it and configured it correctly. Thanks :)